# Как сделать чтобы после прелоадера срабатывал animated.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, frontend

У меня на сайте стоит прелоадер и в header'е установлена анимации с плагина animated.js. Как сделать, чтобы эта анимация срабатывала через определённое время?

Answer (score 0):

для css: `animation-delay`

для js: `setTimeout()`